# Airport transfer in Manila between Terminals 1 and 3

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, short-connections, manila, mnl

I am soon going on a tour to the Philippines (Cebu) with a stop in Manila. There, I need to transfer from terminal 1 (which serves for international flights only) to terminal 3 (domestic flights only). The two flights in and out of Manila are booked on different airlines. According to my search on the internet, I could find out that one may either take a (yellow airport) taxi (for maximum 200 PHP) or use the "new" shuttle service of the airport.

I have only three hours to make the transfer and have to get my luggage and check in for the next flight. Which way should I do it, in order to make my connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the official shuttle, which can cross through airport grounds.  Taxis need to use public roads around the airport, which can get *extremely* (as in, hours stuck in traffic) congested.

Comment: Seconded.  Stay off the public roads if you can.  Manila has extremely bad traffic.  Even so, it will probably not be a very relaxed few hours.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I actually took the white taxi as otherwise I would have to wait half an hour for the next shutle bus. Even though we just had 1h 30min to get from our arriving flight to terminal 3 (plane delayed badly), we could still make it in time, paying 300 PHP for the taxi from terminal 1 to 3. However, we could already see that the other lane / the way back was full of traffic... So we might have been _a bit_ lucky... Still, I hope to be able to get the shuttle bus on the way home. Nevertheless, if your _very_ last chance is using the taxi, it might be worth a try :)

Answer (score 1):

The attached map shows Terminal 1 and Terminal 3. Notice that Terminal 3 is just right in front of Resorts World Manila so you've got a landmark to tell the taxi driver but that should be pretty well known to the driver.

[image: Terminal 3]

Yellow taxis charge an exorbitant rate and has been reported to use dishonest meters. Try to ask help from the security personnel where to catch a regular taxi (there should be a taxi bay). They are cheaper and more often than not are honest enough to charge you fairly and bring you to your destination safely.

Hope you'll enjoy your visit in my beautiful country.

Answer (score 0):

I take transfer at least 3 times a year on international flights to Manila from the US.  The transfer bus has a 30 minutes wait time and takes the public road between terminal 1 and 3.  You have to wait to unload all luggage at terminal 3 and go back through security. Take the yellow taxi and you do not wait for everyone else to get on and off. 
When I fly into terminal 3 from Tacloban the buss takes the private road on the airport Grounds an it the fastest way to go avoid take the taxi.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the official airport shuttle buses, if you are traveling via Philippine Airlines (PAL) or an airline with codeshare flights with PAL, you can avail of PAL's own shuttle service between Terminal 1, 2, and 3.

See: https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/jp/Home/AboutUs/OtherServices/OurServicesFreeTransferService

> **Between NAIA1 and Centennial Terminal 2/new Terminal 3**
>
> Passengers transferring via Manila on Philippine Airlines and
>   International Codeshare flights shall be provided with free shuttle
>   service to and from NAIA Terminal 1, Centennial Terminal 2 and
>   Terminal 3. The passenger is requested to proceed to the Transfer Desk
>   Service at NAIA Terminal 1.
>
> This service is subject to certain conditions and qualifications. For
>   more information, please inquire with any of our Philippine Airlines
>   staff at the arrival area of either terminal.

Before landing, ask the PAL staff for information. You'll have to clear immigration and customs and then proceed to the Transfer Desk (same as where you go for the airport shuttle). PAL staff will then assist you to the PAL shuttle to get you to Terminal 3.